# Re-arrange multi level array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I've been trying to get this thing working. I have this array

```
let materias = [{
  "diasemana": "Lunes",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Gestión de Operaciones I",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Miércoles",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Gestión de Operaciones I",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Gestión de Operaciones I",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Martes",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Jueves",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "12:05:00",
  "hora_inicio": "10:25:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Martes",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Proyecto de Ingeniería I",
  "seccion": "Sección 3",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Miércoles",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Proyecto de Ingeniería I",
  "seccion": "Sección 3",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Proyecto de Ingeniería I",
  "seccion": "Sección 3",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Lunes",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Uso Eficiente de la Energía",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Miércoles",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Uso Eficiente de la Energía",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Uso Eficiente de la Energía",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Lunes",
  "hora_fin": "18:10:00",
  "hora_inicio": "16:30:00",
  "materia": "Taller de Innovación y Fabricación Digital",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Miércoles",
  "hora_fin": "18:10:00",
  "hora_inicio": "16:30:00",
  "materia": "Taller de Innovación y Fabricación Digital",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Sábado",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Taller de Innovación y Fabricación Digital",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Lunes",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Introducción al Desarrollo Sostenible",
  "seccion": "Sección 2",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Jueves",
  "hora_fin": "08:25:00",
  "hora_inicio": "06:45:00",
  "materia": "Introducción al Desarrollo Sostenible",
  "seccion": "Sección 2",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Sábado",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Introducción al Desarrollo Sostenible",
  "seccion": "Sección 2",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Lunes",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Desarrollo Energético Sostenible",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Jueves",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Desarrollo Energético Sostenible",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, ];
```

That has repited 'materias', and I want to get to something like this

```
[{
"materia": "Desarrollo Energético Sostenible",
data: [
 //array with all the days and times (3 for each 'materia')
]
}]
```

Right now, I'me getting the materia item and in data I'm only getting the last occurrence (the last day) of each 'materia'.

How can I get all the occurrences?

Here's a fiddle with what I've done so far.

https://jsfiddle.net/chest94/cf4j6y7h/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```js
const materias = [{
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "20:00:00",
  "hora_inicio": "18:20:00",
  "materia": "Gestión de Operaciones I",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Martes",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Jueves",
  "hora_fin": "10:15:00",
  "hora_inicio": "08:35:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}, {
  "diasemana": "Viernes",
  "hora_fin": "12:05:00",
  "hora_inicio": "10:25:00",
  "materia": "Simulación de Operaciones y Servicios",
  "seccion": "Sección 1",
}];

console.log(groupByMateria(materias));

function groupByMateria(materias) {
  const grouped = [];
  const materiasMap = new Map();

  for (const entry of materias) {
    let materia = materiasMap.get(entry.materia);
    if (!materia) {
      materia = {
        materia: entry.materia,
        data: []
      };
      grouped.push(materia);
      materiasMap.set(entry.materia, materia);
    }

    const dataEntry = Object.assign({}, entry);
    delete dataEntry.materia;
    materia.data.push(dataEntry);
  }
  return grouped;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I wanted.